# AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'left'

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, scikit-image

I have the following code:

```
import numpy
import skimage.io, skimage.color
import matplotlib.pyplot

raspberry = skimage.io.imread(fname="E:\Sem 5\Seminar\ANN\Rasb.jpg", as_gray=False)
apple = skimage.io.imread(fname="E:\Sem 5\Seminar\ANN\App.jpg", as_gray=False)
mango = skimage.io.imread(fname="E:\Sem 5\Seminar\ANN\man.jpg", as_gray=False)
lemon = skimage.io.imread(fname="E:\Sem 5\Seminar\ANN\lemon.jpg", as_gray=False)

apple_hsv = skimage.color.rgb2hsv(rgb=apple)
mango_hsv = skimage.color.rgb2hsv(rgb=mango)
raspberry_hsv = skimage.color.rgb2hsv(rgb=raspberry)
lemon_hsv = skimage.color.rgb2hsv(rgb=lemon)

fruits = ["apple", "raspberry", "mango", "lemon"]
hsv_fruits_data = [apple_hsv, raspberry_hsv, mango_hsv, lemon_hsv]
idx = 0
for hsv_fruit_data in hsv_fruits_data:
    fruit = fruits[idx]
    hist = numpy.histogram(a=hsv_fruit_data[:, :, 0], bins=360)
    matplotlib.pyplot.bar(200, height=hist[0], left=numpy.arange(360))
    matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(fruit+"-hue-histogram.jpg", bbox_inches="tight")
    matplotlib.pyplot.close("all")
    idx = idx + 1
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Sem 5\Seminar\ANN\ann_algo.py", line 21, in <module>
    matplotlib.pyplot.bar(200, height=hist[0], left=numpy.arange(360))
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2653, in bar
    **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1361, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 2365, in bar
    r.update(kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 1062, in update
    raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} object "
AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'left'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show the entire traceback? Your code is not a [mcve] and does not access any property ``left``.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html). The values you're passing to `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` don't make any sense. For example, the first thing passed should be an array or a sequence of arrays, not an integer like `200`. I can't help you fix the problem, because I can't guess what you want the histogram to look like, or how it is supposed to relate to the data.